# how to get coordinates of intersection of line and curve by clicking on intersected points?

Tags: r

I have one non-linear (this curve is plotted using twenty coordiantes) and one linear curve (knowing equation). After plotting them I need to find the point of intersection. May be by clicking on points of intersection.

```
data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T,sep=",")
x<-seq(2.2,22,by=10)
plot(x,data[4])  ##plotting curve##
lines(x,data[4) ## joining points to get curve##
x1<-(0,max(x)
y1<-(0,max(x)*5+45) ## trying to  define straight line##
lines(x1,y1)
```

Comment: `?locator` should work

Comment: If you want to draw straight lines on your plot look at `?abline`.